# How to display local html data(which is in string variable) in web browser in windows phone 8

Tags: html, web, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In my windows phone 8 application, **When I call the web service I'm getting the response. And the response is html code. Now I have stored the html code in string variable. Now I want to show this html code in the web browser.** For this I've used the below code.

```
 myWebBrowser.NavigateToString("myHTMLcode")
```

But the data is not showing in the page. Please tell me how to do the above. I'm looking forward for valuable response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a WebBrowser control in XAML (make sure it has enough height and width set)

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Height=400 Width=300/>
```

Then I created a web client to fetch some html page

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
 client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

When the html is downloaded, show it in our webBrowser control

```
 void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    webBrowser.NavigateToString(e.Result);
 }
```

Adopt this to your needs.

Comment: Hi Chandra, I did as you said, but in my browser it is displaying code. I want the web page with that specified tags. Below is the response.<p><span style="font-family: Times New Roman;">bulk sms en</span><br />
<strong>dfasdfasfd<br />
asdf<br />
asdf<br />
asdf</strong><br />
<span style="font-family: MS Sans Serif;">asdf<br />
asdf<br />
asdf<br />
asdf<br />
asdf</span><br />
<span style="font-family: Courier New;"><br />
<br />
asdfa<br />
sdf<br />
sas<br />
asdf<br />
</span></p>
<ol>
    <li>dfasdf</li>
    <li>asdf</li>
    <li>asfd</li>
    <li>asdf</li>
</ol>

Comment: Construct it as a proper html content .. like `<html><head></head><body>your html content here</body></html>` then it should work !!

Comment: Thank you Chandra, after adding html tags it is displaying.